# ColdFusion looking for files in web service import statements on local machine instead of web server

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I am trying to create a web service object in CF10. I have verified that it works as intended in SoapUI. However, when I run it in CF, I get an error that it cannot find an XSD imported in an import statement in the WSDL. Here is the `createObject` call in CF and the `import` statements within the WSDL:

```
<cfset var ws = createObject("webservice", "https://XXXXXX.XXXX.net/billingandcollectionmgmt/billing/PaymentManagement_1.wsdl")

<xsd:import schemaLocation="PaymentManagement_1.xsd4.xsd" namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="PaymentManagement_1.xsd2.xsd" namespace="http://www.XXXXX.com/schemas/XXXXBilling/billingandcollectionmgmt/billing/PaymentManagement_1"/>
```

The error I'm getting is because it's looking in my local CF install's /bin location to find the files, instead of on the web server in the same directory as WSDL itself. I have verified that the XSDs are indeed located in that directory by accessing them with the URL I provided above. I.e, the file `https://XXXXXX.XXXX.net/billingandcollectionmgmt/billing/PaymentManagement_1.xsd4.xsd` does exist.

Here is the stack trace:

```
javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at 'PaymentManagement_1.xsd4.xsd'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/bin/PaymentManagement_1.xsd4.xsd
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.XmlRpcServiceImpl.getServiceInfoGenerator(XmlRpcServiceImpl.java:468)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.XmlRpcServiceImpl.generateServiceInfo(XmlRpcServiceImpl.java:372)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.XmlRpcServiceImpl.registerWebService(XmlRpcServiceImpl.java:317)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.XmlRpcServiceImpl.getWebServiceProxy(XmlRpcServiceImpl.java:679)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.WebServiceProxyFactory.getProxy(WebServiceProxyFactory.java:22)
    at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:5747)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5710)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5644)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5619)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5566)
    at cfXXXXPayments2ecfc1210176705$funcDELETEPAYMENT.runFunction(C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\XXXXPayments.cfc:74)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2659)
    at cfXXXXPayments2ecfc1210176705$funcDELETEPAYMENTS.runFunction(C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\XXXXPayments.cfc:64)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:655)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:444)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:414)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2432)
    at cftestPending2ecfm428388279.runPage(C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\testPending.cfm:3)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:443)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:204)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/bin/PaymentManagement_1.xsd4.xsd
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(Unknown Source)
    ... 74 more
```

The question is, does anyone know why ColdFusion might be looking for the file on my local machine instead of on the web server where the files are actually located?

Comment: Shouldn't you put the web server URL as part of the schemaLocation?

Comment: @MelanciaUK If that was necessary, why would it work in SoapUI?

Comment: Just a guess. I've never worked with CF.

Comment: Why do you think it is looking at your local machine? The stack trace is from the server and it is referencing `C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/bin/PaymentManagement_1.xsd4.xsd` on the server, not your local machine.

Comment: @Miguel-F Not true, when I download that xsd and put it in C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/bin/ on my PC, it finds it, but fails on the next import

Comment: Are you running ColdFusion on your PC?

Comment: Yes, I have a local install on which I'm testing this. I'm trying to consume a java web service at the URL above using that local install of CF.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I almost always have issues trying to use `createObject` to consume web services. So instead I use `cfhttp` calls.  You have already used SoapUI to call the service so you should be able to use that same request in ColdFusion by using `cfhttp`. [Check my related answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13499890/1636917) I mean you should literally be able to copy the XML from the SoapUI request and past into my sample code and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Miguel's advice, I changed my code to use `cfhttp` and the code snippet in his [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13499890/1636917). Replacing the  `<soapenv:Envelope>  </soapenv:Envelope>` with the content from my SoapUI request solved my problem.